# Error! Some required system tools when trying to apply Magento patches via SSH

Tags: patches

I have been trying to apply some Magento patches via `SSH` (`SUPEE-5344` and `SUPEE-1533`) from the Magento Community Edition download page (https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/)

I am running in a `SSH` session:

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh
```

but keep getting the following error:

> Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed:
>   Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them).

I have tried applying earlier patches but receive the same error message. How do I resolve this to apply the patches?

Comment: Is solve your issue?

Comment: @Rathinam yes see my answer bellow

Comment: How can i install patch package

Comment: I am getting error when i run code : sh patchname.sh

Comment: $ sh xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.sh Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed: Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them).

Comment: see the answer bellow. `yum install patch`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to install the `patch` package:

```
yum install patch
```

or `zypper install patch` for OpenSUSE LINUX.

Then run `sh` the patch file:

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh
```

> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>   Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

Repeat for all missing patches.

*Note: I provided this as I spent quite a bit of time on this before realizing that the error being thrown wasn't for a previous patch but for the patch package itself.*

Comment: For Linux and Macintosh, ie *nix systems since Magento is a *nix native program. For Windows users, a Linux tools environment like Cygwin or individual Gnu tools for Windows will need to be installed. Bit of an extra ride involved there.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution for those who have no SSH access, or having difficulties using sh command to apply for the patch: (community edition)

**With the successful update on the local machine**, find the 5 files on your local machine which have the updates:

> app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
>
> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
>
> app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
>
> app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
>
> lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

upload these files to your server using FTP, and patches are done!

To me, this is a safer option to apply for the patches.

Pls correct me if I am wrong!