# When Trying to Patch Magento 'Tool(s) “patch” is(are) missed, please install it(them)'

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I have been trying to apply some Magento patches.

Code :-

```
print("<PRE>"); 
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-5344.sh");
print("</PRE>");
echo "Done";
```

but getting the following error:-

Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed: Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them).

Comment: I think `patch` package is missing on your server, please install it. Refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64005/2443 for more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error! Some required system tools when trying to apply Magento patches via SSH](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64004/error-some-required-system-tools-when-trying-to-apply-magento-patches-via-ssh)