# Ho can i install Patch on WAMP localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

Localhost magento panel securty alert, **`Community Edition 1.9.X and SUPEE-**** Security Enhancements.`** The patch download and moved to root folder, run by

> sh patchname.sh

Not working Getting error like,

> $ sh xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.sh Error! Some
>   required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not
>   installed: Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them).

How can i solve the issue.

Comment: I am using cygwin

Answer (score 0):

For Cygwin, you may have to re-run the Cygwin setup utility and go select the patch utility package for installation in the Cygwin environment.

And try the following command

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-XXXX.sh
```

Comment: I am getting same using  "bash PATCH_SUPEE-XXXX.sh" and i am added to Envoronmental Variable like "C:\cygwin\bin "

Comment: And my CURRENT_DIR=`$PWD_BIN`/

Comment: Is  patch utility package installed?

Comment: How can i check it?  is patch utility package installed?

Answer (score 0):

You should go at https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-****/
download the patch file folder and drop in magento root folder 
you will get success.

Comment: Thank You surender, you have great stuff. Actually, i need to import patch via ssh for my custom purpose. How can i do it by cygwin or putty for my wamp localhost

Comment: Please Follow these instructions may be help you its magento doc.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

you can put localhost project details in ssh like local IP, username, password and then follow instructions given by magento doc.

Comment: Yes, i followed docs, there will be i getting error :: $ sh xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.sh Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed: Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them).

Comment: ohh
May be this one Help You
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64004/error-some-required-system-tools-when-trying-to-apply-magento-patches-via-ssh/64005